# User-friendly form of entering n by n matrix via command line

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, user-input

What form of entering an *n by n matrix* via the command line seems the most user-friendly to you? Specifically, I am wondering about a user-friendly way to enter the contents an *asymmetrical n x n matrix*, in which all the elements on the main diagonal are equal to 0. The user will need to enter the data via a Python *argparse* argument.

Multiple ways present themselves, and this question appears to be a choice between brevity and legibility. For example, assume the following asymmetrical n x n matrix:

```
   A   B   C
A  0   1   2
B  2   0   1
C  3   0.5 0
```

Under the assumption that the matrix content is provided row-by-row, a form emphasizing brevity may be:

```
user_inp = "1,2,2,1,3,0.5"
```

By contrast, a form emphasizing legibility may be:

```
user_inp = "0,1,2;2,0,1;3,0.5,0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for the row-by-row approach. Typical use case would probably be to write the matrix in a file, and send it to your program with input redirection. This way the user can then just type the file like the matrix logically looks.